# Lazy Loading depth issue in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I created a WEB API project with code first approach (using PostgreSql). Nearly all my classes have relational entities. Writing seperate .Include(..) functions for them every time is not efficient so I've searched and find Lazy Loading and Eager Loading methods [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy).

Every example I found online uses 2 or 3 classes with one relational entities. For example, Task table uses User table, Subtask table and SubtaskClone table. And all of these sub-tables also have a lot of other relational entities.

```
    public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    public string? TaskName { get; set; }

    public int ResponsibleId { get; set; }

    // Relational properties set as virtual for enabling them to lazyLoading method
    public virtual User? User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subtask>? Subtasks { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubtaskClone>? SubtaskClones { get; set; }
}
```

I have more than 7 tables like this and all of them points each other for some relational issues. Since it's pretty inefficient to use Include()- separately for all table classes, I've tried AutoInclude() method inside DbContext class OnModelCreating() method. That created some other problems because when I AutoInclude every relational entity in every class, since some of the classes have two way dependencies, GET function got stuck on loop and crashed. And it's kind of impossible for me to decide which entity to auto-include for every table so I skipped this option.

So I've decided to use LazyLoading. Here is my implementation.

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: false)
             .Build();

        optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
```

Without LazyLoading enabled, this is part of data that GetTasks returns:

```
    {
    "taskId": 2,
    "taskName": "testtask2",
    "responsibleId": 2,
    "user": null,
    "subtasks": null,
    "subtaskClones": null
  },
  {
    "taskId": 3,
    "taskName": "testtask3",
    "responsibleId": 2,
    "user": null,
    "subtasks": null,
    "subtaskClones": null
  },
```

Every relational entity returns null (actually they are not null). But when I enable Lazy Loading, here is just one task's data:

```
{
"taskId": 2,
"taskName": "testtask2",
"responsibleId": 2,
"user": {
  "userId": 2,
  "roleId": 1,
  "userCode": "u001o001",
  "nameSurname": "testuser1",
  "departmentId": 1,
  "teamId": 2,
  "pointsAssigned": 0,
  "pointsEarned": 0,
  "role": {
    "roleId": 1,
    "roleName": "admindev",
    "users": [
      null,
      {
        "userId": 3,
        "roleId": 1,
        "userCode": "u002o002",
        "nameSurname": "testuser2",
        "departmentId": 1,
        "teamId": 2,
        "pointsAssigned": 0,
        "pointsEarned": 0,
        "role": null,
        "department": {
          "departmentId": 1,
          "departmentName": "testdepartment1",
          "teams": [
            {
              "teamId": 2,
              "departmentId": 1,
              "teamName": "testteam1",
              "department": null,
              "users": [
                null,
                null,
                {
                  "userId": 4,
                  "roleId": 1,
                  "userCode": "u002o002",
                  "nameSurname": "testuser2",
                  "departmentId": 1,
                  "teamId": 2,
                  "pointsAssigned": 0,
                  "pointsEarned": 0,
                  "role": null,
                  "department": null,
                  "team": null,
                  "subtaskClones": [],
                  "tasks": []
                },
                {
                  "userId": 5,
                  "roleId": 1,
                  "userCode": "u002o002",
                  "nameSurname": "testuser2",
                  "departmentId": 1,
                  "teamId": 2,
                  "pointsAssigned": 0,
                  "pointsEarned": 0,
                  "role": null,
                  "department": null,
                  "team": null,
                  "subtaskClones": [],
                  "tasks": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "teamId": 3,
              "departmentId": 1,
              "teamName": "testteam2",
              "department": null,
              "users": []
            }
          ],
          "users": [
            null,
            null,
            {
              "userId": 4,
              "roleId": 1,
              "userCode": "u002o002",
              "nameSurname": "testuser2",
              "departmentId": 1,
              "teamId": 2,
              "pointsAssigned": 0,
              "pointsEarned": 0,
              "role": null,
              "department": null,
              "team": {
                "teamId": 2,
                "departmentId": 1,
                "teamName": "testteam1",
                "department": null,
                "users": [
                  null,
                  null,
                  null,
                  {
                    "userId": 5,
                    "roleId": 1,
                    "userCode": "u002o002",
                    "nameSurname": "testuser2",
                    "departmentId": 1,
                    "teamId": 2,
                    "pointsAssigned": 0,
                    "pointsEarned": 0,
                    "role": null,
                    "department": null,
                    "team": null,
                    "subtaskClones": [],
                    "tasks": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              "subtaskClones": [],
              "tasks": []
            },
            {
              "userId": 5,
              "roleId": 1,
              "userCode": "u002o002",
              "nameSurname": "testuser2",
              "departmentId": 1,
              "teamId": 2,
              "pointsAssigned": 0,
              "pointsEarned": 0,
              "role": null,
              "department": null,
              "team": {
                "teamId": 2,
                "departmentId": 1,
                "teamName": "testteam1",
                "department": null,
                "users": [
                  null,
                  null,
                  {
                    "userId": 4,
                    "roleId": 1,
                    "userCode": "u002o002",
                    "nameSurname": "testuser2",
                    "departmentId": 1,
                    "teamId": 2,
                    "pointsAssigned": 0,
                    "pointsEarned": 0,
                    "role": null,
                    "department": null,
                    "team": null,
                    "subtaskClones": [],
                    "tasks": []
                  },
                  null
                ]
              },
              "subtaskClones": [],
              "tasks": []
            }
          ]
        },
```

Actually it goes much more deeper than this for one Task (nearly 3 times longer) but I've cut it since I don't want to make this entry too long.

I need some of this data but I don't want to go this deep. For example, knowing the "User" for Task1 is enough for me. I don't need that user's relational entities for this query (like user's role and details of that role etc.)

How can I keep using Lazy Loading but set the depth of query? Is it possible or should I use another approach? I'm pretty confused since this is the first time I'm using EF Core like this.

Thanks.

edit: Here is the code you I am using to get the data (regarding @RichardHooper 's comment). Actually since I'm trying to improve myself with .NET I'll use Repository pattern but when I implement repository pattern the outcome is the same so here is the initial code I was using to check if my DB works properly. I'm not deleting my comments so you may understand what I tried before :)

```
        //get all the tasks
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Data.Entities.Task>>> GetTasks()
    {
       /* 
        * this is the way to include relational elements to query when it's
        * not configured at onModelCreating or onConfiguring function
        var tasks = await _atmDbContext.Tasks
            .Include(c => c.Subtasks)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.SubtaskClones) //this includes SubtaskClones of Subtask, not TASK!!!!!!
            .ToListAsync();

        return Ok(tasks); */

        return Ok(await _atmDbContext.Tasks.ToListAsync());
```

Now I'm implementing a single GET function for all controllers using Repository Pattern and Unit of work class but like I said before, outcome is same with this code since lazy loading happens at onConfiguring function inside AtmDbContext class.

Comment: Maybe I've used wrong terms to explain the issue. I may say I want to get all relational entities (ICollections you may say) but I don't want all database at once. Simply 1 iteration is enough for me. Can I limit lazy loading with 1 iteration?

So I may call it as an ITERATION issue not DEPTH issue.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to get the data? That might help inform the best options. Please add that to the question.

Comment: @RichardHooper Sorry for the late reply, I've added my GET function at the end of the post.

Comment: The problem I see with your design is that you are directly returning your entities rather than data transfer objects. Once you define proper DTOs, you should revert to explicit `Include()` calls or define your own projections - directly or through automapper.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I'm not very familiar with DTOs but I'll try to understand how to implement them into my project. I can add an example of how I use Repository pattern to get all users if you want to examine. 

Plus, I was using include before lazy loading like you can see on commented section (get function). How is that different than using DTOs and automapper with explicit Include?